# Illegal character in path at index 25

Tags: java, netbeans, java-ee-6

I'm getting an error:

`WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 25: file:/C:/Users/bkuhl/Java_Projects/CMT/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar`

I'm having trouble determining what the cause here might be.  The stack trace is

```
    java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 25: file:/C:/Users/bkuhl/Java_Projects/CMT/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
        at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:936)
.......
```

I'm at a complete loss on where to look.  This same code is working on my co-workers machine so I figure it must be a path problem.  The trouble is, I can't figure out where to look...

Comment: The error message is telling you where to look. Look at the 25th character of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess, your co-worker has no directory "Java_Projects". The 25th character is the underscore "_". Either you change the path or you escape the character.

Usually a [URLEncoder](https://web.archive.org/web/20130624074039/http://docs.oracle.com:80/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) can help in this case.