# Cordova FileTransfer Returning Null Error Code

Tags: android, post, cordova, upload

So, after tinkering with this for a while, I have noticed that the upload() function throws at least the most rudimentary error even if the given upload destination is completely bogus. However, if there's an UNDERSCORE anywhere in the domain (specifically, I need to upload to dev_upload_area.s3.amazonaws.com), like the one I have to upload to, the request doesn't even happen, the uploadFailure function is called with a null error code immediately.

Any help?

EDIT: And yes, access origins are properly set.

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code ? :-)

Comment: What platform? Android, iOS, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem, and I found that RFC stipulates that the underscore is not a valid character in a domain name.
So either you change your url, either you have to modify FileTransfer plugin java source to escape the character.

Sources:

[Illegal character in path at index 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673344/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-25)

[http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=14188](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673344/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-25)

[http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5049974](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673344/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-25)